# htaccess rewrite PNG as JPG in specific directories

Tags: .htaccess, png, url-rewriting, jpeg

Basically I changed image generation on a site from PNG to JPG and converted all existing files to save space. The problem is in requests for the old PNG versions.

This only effected a few specific directories like /imgs/profiles/  for example

I've tried to sort out the rule myself but it's driving me mad.

If anyone could just give me an example for rewriting PNG requests as JPG in /imgs/profiles/ I can sort all the rest for the sake of saving space here.

edit - section of my htaccess top

```
FileETag None
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.net
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.net/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 300 /404.php

RewriteBase /imgs/profiles/
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.png$ /$1.jpg [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^file file.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/imgs/profiles` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /imgs/profiles/

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.png$ /imgs/profiles/$1.jpg [R=301,L,NC]
```

#### EDIT: I'm providing a fix for your .htaccess here:

**Make sure this .htaccess is directly under your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:**

```
FileETag None
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 300 /404.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(imgs/profiles/[^.]+)\.png$ /$1.jpg [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^file/?$ /file.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: hmm when I applied that it did rewrite as jpg but the directory is incorrect

a request for /imgs/profiles/6.png  results in  /imgs/profiles/imgs/profiles/6.jpg

Comment: Aha

changing RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.png$ /imgs/profiles/$1.jpg [R=301,L,NC]

to RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.png$ /$1.jpg [R=301,L,NC]

works, I presume because the base after rewrite is then root

Comment: Yes you're correct about base root. Glad that it worked out for you.

Comment: hmm it worked locally but other requests in htaccess are then also pointed to /imgs/profiles :/

Comment: @FaTe Please add your solution as a new answer instead.

Comment: like rewrite rules example file.php  to /file  now look for  /imgs/profiles/file.php

Comment: @FaTe: May I know where did you place above .htaccess?

Comment: Also above rule is using `^([^.]+)\.png$` regex which will not match any `.php` file.

Comment: @anubhava I edited my question above with a snippet of the top of my .htaccess

Comment: Ah you have quite a few issues in your .htaccess? I can fix it though, just want to now in which directory you've placed above .htaccess file?

Comment: and the only issue is rewrite the png to jpg  everything else works when the answer given is not in place

if I add the answer as given then although you said it only effects png which I know should be the case my server still gives  site.com/file   as   site.com/imgs/profiles/file

Comment: Pls try your edited `.htaccess` as I suggested in answer's edited section now. If `.htacccess` is in root then `RewriteBase /imgs/profiles/` needs to become `RewriteBase /` as suggested in my edit section above.